# Openlayers WMS wrong show OSM, good for google maps

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system, openlayers, wms

I have two maps one is OSM and one is google maps. I want show WMS with projection **EPSG:2180** and when I switch layer to wms then features hidden and show border from WMS but wrong. When I set google map(ol3gl) then it's good to time when map crash - I can't zoom. I upload two images(there where is red, there is good)
Some code with WMS:

```
 proj4.defs("EPSG:2180","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs");
var extent = [171700.190996, 140135.919877, 861883.198003, 774942.471876];
var proj=ol.proj.get("EPSG:2180");
proj.setExtent(extent);

var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:2180',
    extent: extent
});
var WMS=new ol.layer.Tile({
    extent: extent,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://mapserver.bdl.lasy.gov.pl/ArcGIS/services/WMS_BDL/mapserver/WMSServer',
    crossOrigin: null,
    projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:2180'),
    params: {
        'LAYERS': '3',
        'FORMAT': 'image/png',
        'TRANSPARENT':true,
        //'WIDTH':"1070",
        //"HEIGHT":"400",
    },
    serverType: /** @type {ol.source.WMSServerType} */ ('geoserver')
    })
});
//manager['main_osm'].setVisible(false);
//manager['main_google'].setVisible(false);
var _view=new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0], projection),
    zoom: 0,
    extent: [171700.190996, 140135.919877, 861883.198003, 774942.471876],
    projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:2180'),
});
manager["wms"]=WMS;
map.setView(_view);
WMS.setOpacity(0.7);
map.addLayer(WMS);
```

Image bad:
[image]

Image with good result:
[image]

Comment: The WMS you are using is not GeoServer, but in your code you state that it is.

Comment: I changed it for mapserver

Comment: It's not mapserver either

Comment: It's an ArcGIS service​

Answer (score 1):

remove the line:

```
projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:2180'),
```

as the WMS needs to return the image in the projection of your map which OpenLayers will fill in for you. The WMS server should handle the reprojection of your layer to the map's projection (and if it can't it is time to get a new WMS server that can).

Comment: So... Request automaticly generated is EPSG:3857, but then map doesn't show.

Comment: See what I said about needing a better WMS then.